# Linq Select Compound From

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm experimenting with linq compount selects. I find the following query not to return any element:

```
            Dim q = From s In d.GetChildRows("DossierSinistri") _
                    From i In s.GetChildRows("DossierIncarichi") _
                    Select s
```

while the following does:

```
            Dim q = From s In d.GetChildRows("DossierSinistri") _
                    Select s
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the obvious out of the way, have you tried "`Select i`" instead of "`Select s`"?

Comment: it doesn't return a thing either